# JTable - load multidimensional array into table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've been trying to load my array into a JTable object with no luck. So here is my array:

```
int[][] board = {
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4},      
    {1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 8},
    {0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7},
    {0, 0, 4, 5, 3, 8, 9, 0, 0},
    {8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0},
    {7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 1},
    {6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

I went to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html
And there is no constructor for putting int arrays, but there is for subject.

Anyone know a method, thanks!

Comment: Try this: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable(java.lang.Object[][], java.lang.Object[])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Integer[][] board = new Integer[][]{
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4},      
        {1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 8},
        {0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7},
        {0, 0, 4, 5, 3, 8, 9, 0, 0},
        {8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0},
        {7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 1},
        {6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

new JTable(board, new String[]{"columnName1"...});
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two possibilities here: zou can use `Integer[][]` instead of `int[][]` which can be casted to `Object[][]` and this will work with a JTable OR you can write your own data model.

Depending on what you want to achieve in the end you should choose the more appropriate one.

Answer (score 1):

Just try changing the `int` array to an `Integer` array

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class JTableComponent{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  new JTableComponent();
  }

  public JTableComponent(){
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Creating JTable Component Example!");
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  Integer[][] board = {
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4},      
            {1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 8},
            {0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7},
            {0, 0, 4, 5, 3, 8, 9, 0, 0},
            {8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0},
            {7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 1},
            {6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

   String col[] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
  JTable table = new JTable(board,col);
  panel.add(table,BorderLayout.CENTER);

frame.add(panel);
  frame.setSize(800,500);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
```